# Android JNI saving to SD-Card

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, save, android-sdcard

My goal is simple: save data generated with my code to some location onto the sd-card (the real one, not the simulated one)! But it showed to be not that simple. I use the Android SDK together with JNI (for using the Tango C-API) and the lenovo phab 2 pro and I also read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)
However, I found posts, where they simply used the directory "/sdcard" for file storage. Does not work in my case. Next, thing I tried in my main activity is the following code to find first the external device:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
```

resulting in:

```
/storage/emulated/0
```

which unfortunately is not my real SD Card. 
I tried more things to find my external directory but all resulted in the the same path. (I can search for them again if anybody is interested) 
It does not matter what I try, I always land in an error or the fiktive SD-Card.

The following is the code I use:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.projecttango.examples.cpp.hellodepthperception"
android:versionCode="0"
android:versionName="0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library 
        android:name="com.projecttango.libtango_device2"
        android:required="true" />
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name_long"
        android:name=".DepthPerceptionActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and the relevant part (as far as I think) of my c-code:

```
chdir("/sdcard);

  FILE * f_sdcard = fopen("Test.txt", "a");
  if(f_sdcard == NULL) {
    LOGE("Error: File not created: %d", f_sdcard);
  }
```

Comment: `sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`. No that is not a path to an sd card. But to -as the function name tells you- external storage.

Comment: You better concentrate on how to find sd card path. Depending on android version and device its possible.

Comment: @greenapps I already recognized since it did give me back the correct path. Do you habe a better idea on how to do it correctly? As I wrote, I already tried quiet a lot methods on how to get the correct path. All of those brought me to the same path of the fictive external storage.

Comment: As said it depends on android version. You are not reacting with a version.

Comment: the version is 6.0.1

Comment: Have a look at `getExternalFilesDirs()`. The second entry is a path on the sd card..

Comment: Supernice, the directory is:  **/storage/9E38-12F9/Android/data/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.hellodepthperception/files/external** I had this path before without the external file though. @greenapps if you formulate your answer I can give you credits

Comment: I had same issue couple days ago. My resolution was to: -on Android 5+ iterate over all `context.getExternalDirs(null)` with companion of checking `Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(File)`, -on Android 4.4 check block size and block count diff with main memory -on older androids get Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() as there is no other way. But remember if device has USB host it can also be the USB storage and you can't know which is which